# How to make this shape with border radius?

Tags: css

I have trouble reproducing this shape using the border-radius:

[image]

Right now I obtain this:

[image]

Here is my css code (it's inside a grid):

```
 .container-11-1 {
    grid-column: 1;
    grid-row: 1 / 3;
    background: #e4cab6;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 50%;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 50%;
    margin-bottom: 30px; //otherwise the bottom stick to the section below and it's even worse
}
```

Comment: Can you show us your html as well and make a working code-snippet out of that?

Comment: Please show your HTML. probably issue is by `grid-row: 1 / 3`

Comment: your 50% is of the object dimnensions, so you need to simply adjust the ratio to fit the object size ratio.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could just change the percent to pixels or rem or other units.
See if this fits your requirement - https://codepen.io/alstonchan/pen/eYevKZq.

```
border-bottom-left-radius: 10rem;
border-bottom-right-radius: 10rem;
/*or*/
border-bottom-left-radius: 160px;
border-bottom-right-radius: 160px;
```

Answer (score 2):

I have made it for you, check it from the example.
Also, here is from [codepen](https://codepen.io/raajkhan/pen/LYOWrRR) which gives you an idea.

```css
.container-11-1 {
    width: 100%;
    height: calc(100vw - 300px);  /* Calculate `px` as you want*/
    grid-column: 1;
    grid-row: 1 / 3;
    background: #e4cab6;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 50%;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 50%;
    margin: auto;
}
.body{
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="container-11-1"></div>
</body>
```

Comment: This output doesn't look like what OP is trying to achieve

Comment: @Martin, I give here an idea, if I was decreasing width by 50% and increased height then it's will look similar, you can check it from https://codepen.io/raajkhan/pen/LYOWrRR here

Comment: @MeherUllahKhanRaj So apply that in your snippet. this is better.

Comment: Hey, @ArmanEbrahimi, I already added the Stackoverflow default code snippet, as you told I will edit my answer too. Thanks for your suggestions. 

Comment: Hi. I think it is correct if you set `height: 100vw`.